# Nuget Package List not updating

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

The list of available nuget packages for my package source is not updating. I suspect I am only seeing the first few of them as they all begin with A the scroll ends.

If I list them via the command line with
    nuget list -source MySource

They are all listed and there are hundreds of them

If I go to Visual Studio 2015->Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Manage Nuget Packages for Solution->Browse and select MySource from the drop down box, I only see a few, all beginning with the letter A.

My search filter is empty.

I've tried opening and closing Visual Studio

What can I do to see the up to date list of available packages in Visual Studio and install on in my project?

Screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQXIk.jpg

Comment: Are there too many nuget package beginning with the letter A, so that other packages are hidden by the scroll bar  in Visual Studio? Could you please share us the screenshot about issue on the  Nuget Package Manager UI? How about create another nuget source with some packages, check if it still have this issue?

Comment: Nah, there are only 7 listed that begin with the letter A. The scroll bar is at its end just a little past the first page.

Comment: Screenshots added to Question.

Answer (score 0):

> Nuget Package List not updating

To narrow down if the issue related to NuGet. You should select the `nuget.org` from the drop down box, check if it still have this issue. Or you can create a new custom package source with some packages to verify it.

If this issue not occur on the `nuget.org` or new create package source, this issue should be more related to your previous package source. You can check **the permission of this package source if there is sub-folder you cannot access** and **run the Visual Studio as Administrator**.

If this issue also occur on the `nuget.org` or new create package source, this issue should be related to the nuget. Please try to uninstall the Nuget Package Manager from Tools->Extensions and Updates->Installed, then reinstall it.

Hope this helps.